# Managing flutter app and flutter web data locally

Tags: flutter, local-storage, flutter-web

I was working on a project to create a flutter to-do app to store data locally on mobile devices but I am not sure how to save data on local storage or something similar on the web.

So, I want to save the data locally if it is a mobile device and save the data on local storage if it's accessed via the web.

I don't know where to start, please advise.

Comment: Are you using Flutter on server-side and Javascript on the client-side, aiming to store data into Javascript's `localStorage`?

Comment: no, I am using only flutter for the whole project

Comment: @LajosArpad how is Flutter supposed to be used server-side? It is a client side UI software development kit, not a server-side framework of any sorts

Comment: @TonyBorchert I have not much knowledge about Flutter. This is why I am asking about it.

Comment: Understandable, did my comment help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Options

You can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#0547) as it uses shared_preferences_android, shared_preferences_ios and shared_preferences_web (using IndexedDB) for the different platforms, note that this is not relevant for you directly as shared_preferences switches accordingly to the required platform.

Alternatively you can also use [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), as it also supports the web (via IndexedDB) and of course all other Platforms similar to shared_preferences.

The last option that also supports web is [isar](https://pub.dev/packages/isar), it is however the most advanced of the three and is not well suited for this simple application at all.

### Docs

All links link to their respective pub pages with enough docs. The only problem now is when to use which of the package.

### Which to use

The flutter community is pretty divided over this, but as you can see shared_preferences has more likes and is from the flutter team at google themselves. However shared_preferences is very basic and if you are considering to save your own class objects (which is probably of use in an todo app) hive has a steeper learning curve to do so, but imo its better than just serialising it with and from json.

Of course json is completely fine, more so as you are probably a beginner, but for more complex applications hive (and if it gets really complex isar) is much better imo.